# Using a custom tag helper for ruby on rails with a bootstrap navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is that I can't get this helper tag to display at all.

So in **application_helper.rb** I want to have a `<% nav_link(name, path) %>` tag helper to append bootstrap's `.active` class dynamically.

My code is the following:

```
def nav_link(name, path)
    content_tag(:li, :class => active_class(path)) do
        link_to name, path
    end
end

def active_class(path)
    (current_page?(path) ? "active" : "").html_safe
end
```

and I would like to use it like so

```
<% nav_link("Users", users_path) %>
```

My hunch is that there's a variable somewhere that's not properly sanitized. How do I fix this?  Is the html_safe call necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's a typo, you should use `<%= nav_link("Users", users_path) %>`.
Without `=`, nothing will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you have written `<% nav_link(name, path) %>` this executes the code but doesn't print anything.

It should be `<%= nav_link(name, path) %>`

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this Gem, it will do exactly what you want.

https://github.com/vigetlabs/nav_lynx

And here is a method it provides:

```
<%= nav_link_to 'Page', my_path, {}, { :wrapper => 'li' } %>
```